# How to attach stack trace to error log messages in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I run multiple WordPress sites which have multiple themes and plugins from multiple different authors. I always check my error log and try to contact the authors to fix bugs in their code, but a lot of them are logged as something like:

```
PHP Deprecated:  wpmu_new_blog is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 5.1.0! Use wp_insert_site instead. in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 5148
PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Argument #3 is not an array in /wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php on line 376
PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=23688 in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2033
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1635
```

As you can see, the warnings occurred in files inside wp-include, which are available to all plugin/theme/core authors, so there is no way for me to find out who called the deprecated function, passed the wrong function parameters or whatever they did.

I also cannot easily reproduce the error in a dev environment because I don't know what action triggered it.

Everything would be much easier if I could change some PHP (or even server) setting that would cause a stack trace to be appended to each error log message.

This is one of those things that, as common as my problem probably is, Google is unhelpful because all search results try to explain how to append the stack trace to my own code, not to anyone's code.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the Xdebug extension to PHP, which overrides the error logging mechanism of PHP and adds stack traces to errors, warnings, etc. when enabled. See [Xdebug documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/develop#stack_trace).